# Javascript url error after changed xampp localhost to domain.com?

Tags: javascript, php, xampp

I have changed my localhost into example.com, but when I using example.com, I got some error, but when using localhost is fine. Error in javascript.

**Error :**

```
url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/show1/show1' // If using example.com

url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/show1/show1' // Working in localhost/example
```

when I delete index.php, it works :

```
url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>/show1/show1' // working in example.com
```

I am using codeignitier.
Can anyone help me, how to make it work without delete index.php in javascript or advice?

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: in `index.php` just check if you have dead links or non relative file paths